Bi-modal MCMC joint posterior when modeling Normal distribution
I am working on a simple model of price as a way to better understand Bayesian statistics and MCMC. Eventually, I will want to add predictor variables to a linear model, but for now I’m just trying to get a simple case working.
Since price is a non-negative continuous variable, I started by using a LogNormal. By taking the log of each price, I can instead model with a simple Normal distribution. My actual data fits the below simulation data quite well.
I am using the rethinking package in R to help me scaffold the writing of Stan code. I want to add varying effects and let each group find its own intercept, so I cluster on group. I provide a fixed dnorm(8,1) prior to get started; I intend to add multi-level adaptive priors next.
The chains run quickly, but do throw a "4 of 4 chains had an E-BFMI less than 0.2." error. The n_eff and Rhat4 values are decent, around 2300 and 1.00, respectively.
What I don't understand is how the joint probability distribution of sigma and any given alpha can be bi-modal. I see two peaks when plotting. This surprised me, as I expected the sampling to be smooth on a Normal distribution. Conceptually, does this mean that for this example group's intercept, the model estimates the value to be around 7.9 (in this example plot), but the sigmas cluster around two points? Does this point to an effect of outlier prices in the full data, so the model isn't sure what exactly to expect for any particular alpha?

#MWE

library(rethinking)

N <- 2000
price <- rlnorm(N, 7.8, 1)  # gives actual $ amounts like 2502, 1419, 19411, etc. Not log amounts like 7.8
dens(price)
dens(log(price))   # approximately Normal


dat <- list(
  price = log(price),
  group = 1:2000
)

test <- ulam(
  alist(
    price ~ dnorm(mu, sigma),
    mu <- alpha[group],
    alpha[group] ~ dnorm(8, 1),
    sigma ~ dexp(1)
  ), data=dat, chains=4, cores=4
)

precis(test, depth=2)

post <- extract.samples(test)

data <- data.frame(post)
ggplot(data, aes(x=alpha.1, y=sigma)) +
  
  geom_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..), contour_lines = TRUE) +
  
  labs(title = "Joint Probability Distribution, cluster by group, N=2000") 



It was suggested to me on Bluesky to change the prior to a non-centered version: mu <- alpha + z[group]*sigma, z[group] ~ dnorm(0, 1). This does sample much better.
